# Changing the colour of a GeoJSON polygon if user location is within it in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I am wondering if there is a way to change the colour of a polygon got from a geojson file only if the users/browser location is within that polygon if so is there any example or working code that cpild be shared

No code But some pseudocode to give the general idea:

> Function locationWithinPolygon (e) { 
>  if (browserlocation within
> GeoJSONPolygonBoundaries){ 
>   pan to feature 
>  Change colour of
> polygon to white 
>   popUpMessage "Your are within" + polygonName }
>
>  else { 
>  function OnLocationError{ alert(e.message); }  
> map.on("location error" + OnLocationError)  
>  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the turf function [booleanContains](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanContains):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5.1.6/turf.min.js"></script>
```

```
var poly = L.polygon([[22.29227, 114.20847],[32.28227, 110.24847],[42.08227, 114.19847]]).addTo(map)

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)

    var contains = turf.booleanContains(poly.toGeoJSON(),marker.toGeoJSON())
    if(contains){
      poly.setStyle({color: 'green'})
    }else{
        poly.setStyle({color: 'red'})
    }
    
    // fit the map to the marker AND polygon
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(poly.getBounds());
    bounds.extend(marker.getLatLng());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
map.locate()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/s9caf3rh/

**Edit: GeoJSON**

With Multi-Polygons you can use `turf.booleanContains` use instead `turf.booleanPointInPolygon`:

```
geoJsonGroup.eachLayer((layer) => {
          var contains = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(marker.toGeoJSON(), layer.toGeoJSON())
          if (contains) {
            layer.feature.properties.polyWithLocation = true;
            layer.bringToFront();
          }
        });
geoJsonGroup.resetStyle();
```

Instead of calling `.setStyle` we add a flag to the feature properties, so the style still applied when `.resetStyle()` is called.

```
function highlightstyle(feature) {
        if (feature.properties.polyWithLocation) {
          return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.4,
            fillColor: 'green'
          };
        } else {
          return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'gray',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.0
          };
        }
      }
```

You had a few mistakes in your code, I fixed it: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/xgr9opce/

Comment: Looks valid but when reading from a geoJSON file could this be done to see  if a user location is within one of multiple polygons from the file, such as count data?

Here is a live version of what I am working on so could I do this within my county data>
https://ces-web2.southwales.ac.uk/students/18018424/leaflet2.htm

Comment: @WMTS I updated my answer, please don't forgett ot accept this answer as correct